# PHP Carbon & MySQL inserting 9999-31-12 into table ends up as 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am using Carbon to manipulate my dates in my PHP7 / Laravel 5.2 / MySql 5.7 project.

I am trying to insert a date of 9999-12-31 23:59:59 into a timestamp field but it resolves to all zeros when inserted.

My migration creates the column like so:

```
$table->timestamp('end_date');
```

My code generates the date like this:

```
$endDate = Carbon::create(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);
```

I then insert it into the table like this:

```
 ClientSubscription::create([
     'end_date' => $endDate,
 ])->save();
```

I can see (via a screen dump during the migration) that the date is generated correctly as a Carbon instance, like this:

```
ED= : {
    "date": "9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "UTC"
}
```

Yet the result from a query of my table is:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I am careful to not work off this date prior to insertion with Carbon, so I copy this date as soon as it is generated then use the copy to calculate periods, etc.

All other calculated dates (different to this date) insert OK into the field using the same create routine.

What have i missed? Thanks!

Comment: you have a timezone, and it probably got pushed to `10000-01-01 02:59:59`, which is outside the valid range, which causes mysql to replace with the all-zeroes.

Comment: Hey @Marc B awesome and it makes sense! My server is set up in UTC. How do I tell the insert routine to ignore TZ?

Comment: Is the column a DATETIME or a TIMESTAMP?

DATETIME can accept up to '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999', whereas TIMESTAMP can only go to '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'

Comment: Hi @ P. Gearman, I declared it as Timestamp (see above) in the migration. Thanks.

Comment: My question is why you want to store something for that far ahead in time?

Comment: @catsis cause I want this date to be the max date available, as in "no end subscription"

Comment: Yeah, so if it's a TIMESTAMP, then trying to store anything outside the normal range is going to store '0000-00-00 00:00:00' instead. (I just tested this on a local project.)

If you change the column to a DATETIME, then you can store things with the year 9999

Comment: *I want this date to be the max date available, as in "no end subscription"* ... then why not allow the field to be `NULL` and use that for *no expiry*? You are basically saying "I have no idea when this expires" ... which seems a reasonable use case for `NULL`?

Comment: I think I got your problem here. You use the create() method in `Carbon::create(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59)`, okay, try to add the timezone by using this code: `Carbon::create($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $timezone);`.

Comment: Hi @Robin R., my server is set up in UTC and if you see the screen dump during the migration, the date is reported correctly and in utc by the carbon object.

Comment: a better solution is to use a dedicated field to indicate "no expiry". magic numbers like `9999` are how the whole y2k mess came around. not particularly likely that your system will still be around for the y10k and y100k cutovers, but why not just build a robust system from the get-go instead of hoping it'll be replaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the suggestion from @CD001 and set the date to null.

My migration now is:

```
$table->timestamp('end_date')->nullable();
```

Then instead of checking for 9999 date like this:

```
if($endDate->year == 9999) {
```

I check like this:

```
if(! $endDate) {
```

This works. Thanks @CD001!

Comment: That's doubly good because `year = 9999` isn't a check, it's an *assignment*.  Using "magical" values causes [all kinds of problems](http://newsfeed.time.com/2012/02/18/mans-vanity-license-plate-attracts-20000-in-erroneous-tickets/). Try to avoid that whenever possible. If there's no end of subscription then `NULL` is the value you want.